# Share images on whatapp and facebook

Tags: php, html

I am getting a problem in sharing images only on whatapp and facebook.
I am using below code for whatapp:
Whatsapp 
in href using https://web.whatsapp.com/send?data=http://mopyshopee.com/uploads/1565768601_ms_1_512_2643685.jpg

but it is sending as url. I want to send share only image from my site(html,php).

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

But you could show preview image and description with the URL. When the URL shared, Whatsapp looks for [ogp](https://ogp.me/) tags on the page. If the tags available, it will automatically gather the necessary tags and parse them into the shared message.

For more information, you could check the [Open Graph Protocol](https://ogp.me/) documentation.

See the example below:

[image: WhatsApp Meta]

Comment: Thanks, Only i want to share image without title and description.

Comment: Sadly, this is not possible.